# Android @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is marked as unresolved reference

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout, androidx, coordinator-layout

I am using androidx dependencies, everything is working fine. But the linter assumes that @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is an unresolved reference. See image below:

[image]

The code itself totally works fine, no problems. I just want to get rid of the linter / inspection to make the error go away. Seems weird by I already tried these things:

- Clean, Rebuild
- Invalidate caches & restart
- Dependecy check on coordinator layout, constraints / androidx

If you are wondering I am using

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha5
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout Behaviors such as `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` are part of `coordinatorlayout` and 
As per [Migration Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) `coordinatorlayout`is now a Separate library not part `appcpmpat`. 
Add it gradle :-

`androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0`.

Comment: Imported the said above, but still shows the linter error (which wasn't here even before when it was freshly migrated to androidx). It also works even without the coordinatorlayout import though... weird.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:
It's fixed now in Android Studio 3.4.1 as described in [the release notes](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/05/android-studio-341-available.html).

---

It's a bug somewhere in the tools, probably the layout editor. You can't disable the inspection and you can't do anything to workaround it except staring the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131403371

Just ignore the inspection for now as you said it works fine without any problems!